# Delphi - replace control WindowProc and dispatch the message

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2, windows-messages

Starting from [Way of getting control handle from TMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764395/way-of-getting-control-handle-from-tmessage) question, I've created my own implementation in order to replace the [Windowproc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.WindowProc) with my own one, in order to make some processing when mouse left button is pressed.

```
  TOverrideMessage = class
  public
    FControl: TWinControl;
    FOldWndProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure OverrideWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
  end;
```

implementation:

```
procedure TOverrideMessage.OverrideWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN then
    begin
      FOldWndProc(Message);
      if FControl is TSomeCustomControl then
        ShowMessage(TSomeCustomControl(FControl).Caption);//this property exists
    end
  else
   Dispatch(Message);
end;
```

And replace the windowprocs of each of the controls I want with an instance of my class:

```
  LOverrideMessage := TOverrideMessage.Create;
  LOverrideMessage.FControl := TSomeCustomControl(lControl4);
  LOverrideMessage.FOldWndProc := TWinControl(lControl4).WindowProc;
  TWinControl(lControl4).WindowProc := LOverrideMessage.OverrideWindowProc;
```

The problem I have is that the messages are not dispatched correctly further to the controls so the controls are not drawing correctly,etc. Also I'm not receiving the WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN message in the class implementation. What's wrong?

Comment: You need to call FOldWndProc(Msg) in your OverrideWindowProc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is the failure to call `FOldWndProc`. You need to call that rather than `Dispatch`. When you call `Dispatch` you will get the base `TObject` handling, which does nothing.

```
procedure TOverrideMessage.OverrideWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  FOldWndProc(Message);
  if Message.Msg = WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN then
    if FControl is TSomeCustomControl then
      ShowMessage(TSomeCustomControl(FControl).Caption);//this property exists
end;
```

If `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` doesn't arrive, then the message is not being sent to your control.

I am concerned by your casting. When you write:

```
LOverrideMessage.FControl := TSomeCustomControl(lControl4);  
LOverrideMessage.FOldWndProc := TWinControl(lControl4).WindowProc;
TWinControl(lControl4).WindowProc := LOverrideMessage.OverrideWindowProc;
```

why do you need any of those casts? If `lControl4` was derived from `TWinControl` then you would not need those casts. If `lControl4` has a compile time type that is less derived, then at least include an `is` check.